# Main dropdown menu text directs to a page, dropdown options direct to anchor points on the page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, nav

At the moment with the code I have, the dropdown menu works and shows the other options, however when you click the actual "Trading" text, which is the main text for the menu, nothing happens, it doesn't take you towards the intended page.

I'm using the latest version of Bootstrap

```
<li class="dropdown">
  <a href="trading.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Trading <span class="caret"></span></a>
  <div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="a.html">Product Group A</a></li>
       <li><a href="b.html">Product Group B</a></li>
       <li><a href="c.html">Product Group C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</li>
```

The above code is part of a navbar.

What I have pictured in my head is this: When you click on the menu button "Trading"

```
<a href="trading.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Trading <span class="caret"></span></a>
```

I need it to take you the the page that the href is pointing it to "trading.html"

I also want it so that when you `hover` over "Trading" you get a dropdown menu that have the three options provided

```
<div class="dropdown-menu">
    <ul>
       <li><a href="anchor point A on trading">Product Group A</a></li>
       <li><a href="anchor point B on trading">Product Group B</a></li>
       <li><a href="anchor point C on trading">Product Group C</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

I plan to create the "Trading" page with three sections that each have their own anchor points, one for each product groups in the dropdown menu.

When you click on "Trading", I want it to take you to the top of the page. However, say you click on "Product Group B", I want it to take you to the "Trading" page, but to take you to the anchor point on the page that is linked to that section.

Hopefully, I have explained it well enough for professional to understand and may be provide me with some help.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

What about using a split button?

http://codepen.io/Sixl/pen/VPJawG?editors=1111

For some reason the "main button" gets styled differently when using `<a class="btn">` instead of `<button class="btn">` inside the group. So you would need to correct the styles to use it with a normal anchor tag. But shouldn't be too much trouble